# Parallel execution in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, execution

In MATLAB, when I use the `numlabs` instruction in the Command Window after calling `parpool(4)`, it is 1. But, when I use the same instruction in the parallel command window it is 4, Why?

```
>> parpool(4)
Starting parallel pool (parpool) using the 'local' profile ... connected to 4 workers.

ans = 

 Pool with properties: 

            Connected: true
           NumWorkers: 4
              Cluster: local
        AttachedFiles: {}
          IdleTimeout: 30 minute(s) (30 minutes remaining)
          SpmdEnabled: true

>> numlabs

ans =

     1

>> pmode start
Starting pmode using the 'local' profile ... connected to 4 workers.

numlabs 4 4 4 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`numlabs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/numlabs.html) returns the "total number of workers operating in parallel on current job". If you type the command after starting a pool, there obviously won't be any ongoing job. Also from the `numlabs` documentation:

> In an spmd block, numlabs on each worker returns the parallel pool size.
>
> However, inside a parfor-loop, numlabs always returns a value of 1.

If you just want the number of workers, you can use [`gcp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gcp.html) (get current pool):

```
hp = gcp;
hp.NumWorkers
```

Comment: Hi horchler, Thank you very much for this answer. Actually, I would like to execute any function in parallel by sending this function to each worker and all workers execute in parallel, how can I do that ?

Comment: You're welcome. Comments are not the place to ask completely new questions. You should formulate a specific question indicating that you've done research, read the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/distcomp/) (and [videos](http://mathworks.com/videos/series/parallel-and-gpu-computing-tutorials-97719.html)), and tried something yourself. Include the code you tried and any errors/issues you have. There's no one correct/best way to do what you want – it would depend on the specifics of your problem, in particular how your data is structured, but you should probably start with `parfor`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try to execute what you said and I will ask new question when I face another problem. Thanks.

Comment: Hi @ammaralabdalazeez if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hi Daniel, yes those answers helped me to find the solutions.

Answer (score 2):

I think that is normal behavior, since `numlabs` should return 1 when not used inside a `spmd` block or during a parallel job. What you have done above is only open the parallel pool, but not asking it to do a parallel job.

I can't test right now, but if you call something like this:

```
spmd

   some statement with numlabs

end
```

you will see printed in the Command Window that you are indeed using the 4 available workers.